# Cakephp3 formatting date issue in query

Tags: sql, cakephp-3.0

I am trying to format my date with this code:

```
$events->formatResults(function (\Cake\Datasource\ResultSetInterface $results){
                return $results->map(function ($row) {
                    $row['date'] = date_format($row['date'],"Y-j-d");

                    return $row;
                });
            });
```

It seems to mostly work but I found this issue. one one field when I format this date:

```
2017-06-17
```

my result turns it into this:

```
"date": "2017-17-17",
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is this not the right way to format the date?

Comment: If you're using proper types, `$row['date']` will be a [**Chronos**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/chronos.html) based date/time object, so you can use the methods provided by it for formatting. That being said, the actual issue here hardly seems to be more than a typo. look at your [**formatting pattern**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and check what `j` stands for.

Comment: for date_format it shows:     j - The day of the month without leading zeros (1 to 31)

Comment: Also $row['date'] has type DATE in mySql

Comment: My fault it should have been an 'n' not a j